# Solve algebraic equation with operations

Tags: python, numpy, math, sympy

Is there a practical solution to the following equation with sympy or numpy? I've tried numpy and sympy so far.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve

sig = symbols(['sig'])

result = linsolve([(sig * -3) + ((1 - sig) * 1) == (sig * 2) + ((1 - sig) * 0)], sig)
```

This code returns an error:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong syntax for linsolve this works:

```
sig = symbols(['sig'])

result = linsolve([(sig * -3) + ((1 - sig) * 1) - (sig * 2) - ((1 - sig) * 0)], sig)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are only interested in solving the equation with sympy or numpy and not necessarily restricting yourself to linsolve, here is working code.

```
from sympy import *
sig = symbols('sig')
eq = Eq((sig * (-3)) + ((1 - sig) * 1), (sig * 2) + ((1 - sig) * 0))
solveset(eq, sig)
```

One problem with your code is that the return value of symbols(['sig']) is not a Sympy symbol object but a python *list* containing one such object, so you cannot use it to build Sympy expressions.